# Difference between single and dual rail op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I don't understand why some op-amps are specified as being dual rail, and others as single rail. Since (AFAIK) none have a ground pin, there is no difference between connecting the positive supply to +10v / the negative supply to -10v, or the positive supply to +20v and the negative supply to ground. Either way, the difference is 20v!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From a purely theoretical POV an opamp is nothing more than a (extremely large-gain) differential amplifier, i.e. an amplifier whose output is an amplified replica of the difference between its two inputs.

The problem with this view, usually found in introductory material/courses on opamps, is that it doesn't take into consideration how power is to be provided to the opamp. Input and output voltages are simply referred to ground, without showing how the component is supposed to know where the ground is (almost as if it were psychic)!

Of course you know that opamps have two power supply terminals, but neither one is labeled "ground", so how the opamp is supposed to know where ground level is? Well, it doesn't know! It simply assumes it is half-way between its two power supplies. That's why you power them up with a symmetric supply. If you didn't you wouldn't get 0V between output and ground when your inputs are shorted together (0 V differential input, and I'm neglecting common mode input to simplify things). The reason for this design choice is twofold:

- opamps are meant to be used also as DC coupled amplifiers, therefore to amplify a differential signal, which can have either polarity, the output must be able to go negative, and for this to be possible you need a negative supply also.
- For a single-supply DC coupled amplifier it is difficult to reach a 0V output level without special circuitry. Older opamps or opamps not meant to be "rail-to-rail" cannot force their output too near the rails, when the negative supply is grounded the output cannot reach 0V (usually the best you can have is 1V above ground, or there about).

Rail-to-rail opamps are designed with more sophisticated circuitry that can bring the output very near the rails (tens of millivolts, maybe less) so they can bring the output really near 0V when used with a single supply, especially if designed to be operated in single-supply mode.

As an aside, although theoretically it is possible to power an opamp with two different positive supplies (e.g. 5V and 25V), because the "difference is 20V", the problem is the other parts of the external circuit. If in such a setup you put a voltage of 0V across one input and ground, actually you are providing a -5V voltage relative to the "lower" 5V supply, which usually means frying something inside the opamp!

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why this answer is not useful in his/her view?

Comment: "It simply assumes it is half-way between its two power supplies. " This is incorrect. An op amp, dual rail or single rail, does not need a ground reference. As a differential amp, its input is the difference between the two input voltages, no ground reference required. It is always used with a feedback loop, which sets the DC zero operating point, (and AC gain), so the output needs no internal ground reference either. The discussion around this point ("incorrect" intro courses, symmetrical supplies) is thus wrong. Op amps work fine with arbitrary mismatched supply voltages, like +12V and -5V.

Comment: "you wouldn't get 0V between output and ground when your inputs are shorted together"  With real op amps you don't get a zero output when shorting the inputs because they have some input offset voltage or current characteristic, which, when multiplied by the gain of 10^5 or 10^6 will provide an output at one rail or the other, or at some arbitrary voltage in between.

Comment: @gwideman Please, reread my post and tell me where in my post are the statements you are objecting to. In your comment you continue to cite a "ground reference" as I had mentioned it. But I never mentioned the need of a ground reference! I just stated the contrary! Even in opamp datasheet there is usually a note that voltages are referred to the negative supply terminal.

Comment: @gwideman And wrt to your comment "Op amps work fine with arbitrary mismatched supply voltages, like +12V and -5V", I didn't say the contrary! I also said it could be fine to power them from "+20 and +5V", but (as a caveat to a newbie) I prompted to be careful because if one is not well aware where the lower rail sits wrt to *system ground*, they could put an input at 0V (assuming is fine), whereas that would be -5V wrt to *opamp local ground", which is its negative supply rail (and that would make the opamp go POOF!).

Comment: @gwideman As for the offset comment, that is not relevant, too. In the opening of my post I addressed *ideal opamps* ("purely theoretical POV"), where offset voltage doesn't exist (otherwise I should have mentioned a lots of other non-ideality issues like bias currents, slew rate, etc.). So you are barking up the wrong tree here. If you are the initial downvoter I prompt you to reconsider and I advice you to *read well* a post before acting.

Comment: "where in my post are the statements you are objecting to. "As I already quoted, it's your statement ""It simply assumes [ground] is half-way between its two power supplies."  An op amp does not need to make any such an assumption, and indeed does not do so. So there's no basis for your statement "That's why you power them up with a symmetric supply." You may have made other comments that moderate the statements I point out here, but that doesn't make these particular statements any less wrong with their misleading implications.

Answer (score 2):

It is convenient in many applications to have a voltage reference point somewhere between the most positive rail and the most negative rail. This is usually called 0V.

0V can come from the power supply and feed to the op-amp circuit or, 0V can be "constructed" by using a potential divider and maybe another op-amp to produce a "mid-rail" signal. You can also generate a negative supply from a positive supply.

All op-amps that operate in **linear** circuits **have** to be "biased" somewhere in between the two power rails and this means either the input itself contains that bias naturally OR you have dual supplies OR you manufacture a mid-rail or negative rail. By "bias" I mean they have a dc operating point that is not end-stopped against the rails.

The upshot of what I'm trying to say is that op-amps don't care how you do this and if the data sheet specifies dual rail then a single rail of twice the voltage will be fine. I'm not saying this rule applies 100% because that would be stupid BUT I can't think of one so-called dual-rail op-amp that cannot work with a manufactured mid-rail.

Comment: Dual rail may be not performing very well close to the supply voltage, but single rail IMHO presumes than it can go all the way to 0 without problems.

Comment: @ilkhd No it doesn't, a rail-to-rail op-amp presumes it can go to 0V without significant problems. Technically any op-amp has to work within the rails and the extent to which its inputs can work down to 0V depends on other factors. Some work at or slightly below 0V whilst unable to get close to the positive rail. Others work at the positive rail or slightly higher. The output can never fully encompass either the positive or negative rail (even on so-called R2R op-amps)

Comment: I would think that single rail would be stable at the negative rail (ground in this case) because this the expected mode of operation in the single supply circuits.

Comment: @ilkhd It is expected that any op-amp in any circuit whether dual or single rail will be able to go reasonably close to both rails, wherever they are.

Comment: @ilkhd you would be wrong with that assumption or generalism.

Comment: @Andyaka poster Lorenzo Donati elaborated my thoughts better than me myself.

Answer (score 0):

"Single rail" typically means that the op amp has some features that allow it to be useful in a system that lacks a negative supply, such as a mostly-digital system or battery powered system. Those scenarios have a relatively low total supply voltage, such as 5V or 3V (or less).
So this probably means a design capable of outputs to, or close to, the rails ("RtoR", given small output load), plus an internal design that functions with a low voltage supply, and *may* also mean inputs that can operate with voltages below the negative rail.
You are correct that none of that makes a "Single rail" op amp operable *only* with a single rail. It just makes it more suited to this scenario of available rails than a conventional dual rail op amp would be.

Comment: i think that single supply stuff commonly has the negative supply (or at least one of the supplies) in the input voltage range.

Comment: Opamps marketed as "single-supply" are as old as the venerand LM358, also called "ground-sensing" because the common mode range includes the negative supply rail (i.e. opamp *local ground*). "Rail-to-Rail" opamps are a more modern invention (with further distinction between RtR *output* and RtR *input/output*. The former ones can swing their *output* to few mV from both rails, the latter also includes the rails in their common mode input range. Inputs below negative rail is almost always ruled out, and will most probably damage something in the opamp (unless there is some protection circuit).

Comment: "It just makes it more suited to this scenario of available rails than a conventional dual rail op amp would be." Wrong It's not something about suitability, it just won't work. An opamp that is not "single-supply" (e.g. the obsolete LM741 or the venerable TL071/TL081) or is not "RtR input" *cannot* operate with its input near its rails. It will saturate. End of the story,

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine A 741 will not be the most convenient for single rail, but certainly works with a single rail. Sure, I agree that the 741's inputs have to stay within some window that is less than the rails, and same with the outputs.  But if using a single supply, you would arrange for the voltages used in the signal path to fulfill those requirements.  There's no fundamental requirement that the input or output voltage range has to include ground. You just arrange for the signal to center on mid-rail, or some other scheme that keeps it within the the op amp's operating range.